# How do I fix the Implicit textOnly message that appears when starting an Express server?

Tags: node.js, express, pug

When starting Express server with `node app.js` I see the following message displayed:

> Implicit textOnly for `script` and `style` is deprecated.  Use `script.` or `style.` instead.

What does this message mean and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[This](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/issues/875) issue and [this](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/pull/1036) pull request discuss the message in detail.  Basically you will soon have to tell Jade explicitly that a script is text only.  The current method of:

```
 script
   var a = 2;
```

is deprecated.  It will be replaced with:

```
script.
  var a = 2;
```

So to fix this message you need to explicitly show that the block is text by adding a dot after `script` or `style`

As stated [here](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/issues/875#issuecomment-20711930) this is being removed to make Jade easier to learn and to permit the use of Jade code blocks in the block.

As I mentioned above, this applies to implicit `style` as well.